# Handle different dataType getting from server using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a RESTful web service which returns data in XML format.
but how to handle the ajax response, if i supposed to mentioned dataType as JSON.

for example,

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "GET",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "JSON"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Is is there any solution to handle this type of Scenario.

Comment: If your request returns JSON, have function to process JSON, if it returns HTML - process HTML. There is hardcoded way to process any type of response, but it's too wide.

Comment: I have received this question from the interviewer